# ggplot2 theme: axis.text not inheriting from text?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The current documentation for `theme` element `axis.text` says:

> axis.text
>
> tick labels along axes (element_text; inherits from text)

but it seems like the inheritance isn't working.

This code gives the plot below, with axis text in grey.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(color='red') +
  theme(rect = element_rect(fill = 'black'),
        line = element_line(color = 'white'),
        text = element_text(color = 'blue'),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image: plot 1, wrong color]

Setting `axis.text` explicitly works, but I was expecting code snippet 1 to already produce this result

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(color='red') +
  theme(rect = element_rect(fill = 'black'),
        line = element_line(color = 'white'),
        text = element_text(color = 'blue'),
        
        # *** setting this explictly ***
        axis.text = element_text(color = 'blue'),
        
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image: plot 2, right color]

I'm starting from a fresh R session, with this `sessionInfo()`

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.6 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_2.2.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] labeling_0.3     colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.4.1     assertthat_0.1   lazyeval_0.2.0  
 [6] plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.3.1      gtable_0.2.0     tibble_1.1       Rcpp_0.12.6     
[11] grid_3.3.1       munsell_0.4.3
```

How can I specify high-level theme elements and let those settings cascade down via inheritance? Do I need to somehow 'clear' the default theme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that your call to `theme()` in the first example results in an "incomplete" `theme` object.

Consider:

```
attr(theme(rect = element_rect(fill = 'black'),
           line = element_line(colour = 'white'),
           text = element_text(colour = 'blue'),
           panel.background = element_blank()), "complete")
```

This should return `FALSE`.  My understanding is that a call to `theme()` when the theme is incomplete does not have all of the inheritance.  A theme like `theme_grey()` is complete and so inheritance works.  I'm not 100% positive however, but this line in the documentation seems to suggest it.

> The object returned by a call to a complete theme function is now a
>   nested list of theme elements and their properties, which enables the
>   new theming system to support inheritance of properties.

Look at [this page](http://docs.ggplot2.org/dev/vignettes/themes.html), specifically the section called **"Complete and incomplete theme objects"**.  It discusses the same issues with color there, and shows you how to create your own [complete] custom theme where inheritance works.