# GGPlot2 axis ticks and tick labels not following theme specification

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to set perfectly black ticks and labels in ggplot2 but they are coming with a very slight grey tint. Here is an example:

```r
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>% ggplot(aes(x = cty, y = cyl)) + geom_point() + theme_classic() +
  theme(line =  element_line(size = 4,color = "black",lineend = "square"),
        text = element_text(color = "black", face = "bold",size = 24))
```

Plots this:
[image]

The color difference in the ticks is subtle but noticeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach with modifications on `theme()`:

```
library(tidyverse)

mpg %>% ggplot(aes(x = cty, y = cyl)) + geom_point() + theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(color = "black", face = "bold",size = 24),
        line =  element_line(size = 4,color = "black",lineend = "square"),
        text = element_text(color = "black", face = "bold",size = 24),
        axis.ticks = element_line(size = 4,color = "black",lineend = "square"))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Found some more insight into my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006924/ggplot2-theme-axis-text-not-inheriting-from-text

Comment: @JordanMandel Hi Jordan. When using `ggplot2` some of the elements have their own defined properties as you see in the answer. Sometimes other options as the ones set by you did not work. It can also depend of other factors like package version. I hope this helped.