# ggplot2: theme(axis.text=element_text(size=3) does not change font size on the y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

Using this code

`FigureS8 <- plot(nonParametricBoot, "edge", plot = "difference", onlyNonZero = TRUE, order = "sample")`

returns a figure where text labels on x- and y-axis are too big.

I therefore added theme():

```
FigureS8 <- plot(nonParametricBoot, "edge", plot = "difference", onlyNonZero = TRUE, order = "sample")
FigureS8 + theme(axis.text=element_text(size=3))
```

Now font size on labels on the x-axis becomes smaller (as I want), but there are no changes to the fontsize on the y-axis. How can  I change the font size on both?

Comment: It looks like you are combining base plotting and ggplot which may be causing your issue. Additionally, you could try using `axis.text.y` to specify y axis settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you haven't specified which axis you want to change in you code, the `axis.text` is interpreted as applying only to the `x` axis, as that is always the first axis to be dealt with.

Therefore code should be:

```
+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 3),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 3))
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be an instance of this problem: [ggplot2 theme: axis.text not inheriting from text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41006924/ggplot2-theme-axis-text-not-inheriting-from-text)

Your theme needs to be 'complete' in order for axis.text.y to inherit from axis.text correctly. So either define a complete theme or just define both axis.text.x and axis.text.y